# How to configure IndexBasedSpellChecker in solr?

Tags: linux, apache, solr

I'm using solr 5.2 and I want to use **IndexBasedSpellChecker** inside my searchHandler,and this is my searchcomponent for IndexBasedSpellChecker:

```html
<searchComponent class="solr.SpellCheckComponent" name="spellcheck">
<str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">text_en_general</str>
  <lst name="spellchecker">
    <str name="name">default</str>
<!--specify a field to use for the suggestions-->
    <str name="field">body-en</str>
    <str name="classname">solr.IndexBasedSpellChecker</str> 
    
  <!-- <str name="distanceMeasure">internal</str> -->
<!--The accuracy setting defines the threshold for a valid suggestion-->
 <!--   <float name="accuracy">0.05</float> -->
<!-- maxEdits defines the number of changes to the term to allow-->
    <int name="maxEdits">2</int> 
<!--defines the minimum number of characters the terms should share-->
   <int name="minPrefix">1</int> 
<!--defines the maximum number of possible matches to review before returning results-->
    <int name="maxInspections">5</int> 
<!--defines how many characters must be in the query before suggestions are provided-->
    <int name="minQueryLength">4</int> 
<!-- sets the maximum threshold for the number of documents a term must appear in before being considered as a suggestion-->
    <float name="maxQueryFrequency">0.01</float> 
<!--sets the minimum number of documents a term must appear in-->
    <float name="thresholdTokenFrequency">.01</float>
```

my problem here is that when I want to use accuracy it gives me this error

```
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: java.lang.Float cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

and when I comment this setting, it will give me another error for using distanceMeasure :

```
 org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'internal'
```

and when I coment both of them ,I can't get the result from my spellchecker,and when I query a phrase it just spellcheck the the first word of the phrase,what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the full component description so I can't say for sure what's going on. If you have more than one spellchecker inside that component make sure it has the same field name.

```
<str name="field">body-en</str>
```

The following code works for me:

```
<searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
    <lst name="spellchecker">
        <str name="name">default</str>
        <str name="field">variations</str>
        <str name="classname">solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker</str>
        <str name="distanceMeasure">internal</str>
        <float name="accuracy">0.5</float>
        <int name="maxEdits">2</int>
        <int name="minPrefix">1</int>
        <int name="maxInspections">5</int>
        <int name="minQueryLength">4</int>
        <float name="maxQueryFrequency">0.01</float>
        <float name="thresholdTokenFrequency">.01</float>
    </lst>
</searchComponent>
```

with the following request handler snippet:

```
<str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
<str name="spellcheck">true</str>
<str name="spellcheck.count">3</str>
<str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
<str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">true</str>
<str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
```

Hope it helps!